# Trouble setting label text property with Eval

Tags: asp.net, label

Does any of you know why this is not possible?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWordSes" Font-Bold="True" EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" runat="server" Text="<%# string.Format(Eval("Word1").ToString()) %>"></asp:Label>
```

i am trying to set the text value with data from the database but i can get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Text attribute you need to do like that:

```
Text="<%# string.Format("{0}",Eval("Word1").ToString()) %>">
```